# I think I’m having endianness problems replicating the results of this paper?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

So I am trying to implement the HHL algorithm depicted in this paper titled 'Quantum Circuit Design for Solving Linear Systems of Equations' by Cao et. al (https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2232v2), but if I copy what they did, then I don't achieve good results. I think this is because my system uses a different endianness. So what I have done is developed a quantum phase estimation algorithm that works for my system. Then I implemented the controlled y-axis rotation gates in the same manner as in the paper.

From here, the implementation of the swap gates in the manner of the paper didn't seem to work and I really don't understand yet how the implementation of the swap gates works, so I just tried implementing swap gates for all possible combinations of qubits 1 through 4 (with qubit 1 being the second qubit or the first qubit that is not the ancillary qubit). From this I found that if the swap gate was between qubits 1 and 4, then I obtained an output state that corresponded to (-1,7,9,13) when I should be getting (-1,7,11,13). Obviously, the weird thing about this is that three of the numbers in my output are exactly right and the other number is exactly a distance of two away from where it should be, which considering that this output is continuous, a distance of exactly two is pretty bizarre.

Then I also found that if I implemented this algorithm in the same way described above with the exception that the unitaries in the controlled unitaries implemented in the quantum phase estimation portion of the algorithm along with the uncomputation of the QPE (but not the controlled y-rotation gates) become the complex conjugate of what they once were, then I achieve an output of (-1,11,7,13). This would be fantastic, but the 11 and 7 are switched from where they are supposed to be. This is the most minor of strange annoyances, but still very important. I know that once I moved away from the quantum phase estimation portion of this algorithm, my processes become somewhat unscientific, but I am just wondering if anybody has any idea how to deal with my issues. I seem to be so close, but this last step seems like it could take a long while to figure out.

Comment: Could you please share you code? It will help to debug your implementation.

Comment: some spacing and better structuring would probably greatly enhance the readability of the question. Walls of text can be quite hard to parse

Comment: @glS I have edited my question so that it is less of a wall of text. I can edit more if you think that is a good idea, but I am about to answer my own question, which is why I haven't put an enormous amount of effort into making this look perfect.

Comment: @MarkS I have made all the edits you requested.

Answer (score 1):

So, I am almost 100% sure that this is a problem of working with a different endianness than other people. I have solved this problem (pretty sure) on my own and this is what I have learned with respect to re-creating algorithms that have a different endianness:

1. If you can divide your algorithm into sub-algorithms, like you can with quantum phase estimation (QPE) for this algorithm, then first get this simpler algorithm to work. Every debugger knows that getting a simpler algorithm to work before the larger algorithm is the way to go, but then they need to be reminded of it.
2. If you are not the person who was the most mathematically brilliant person in your quantum physics/other science course, then you need to play around with reversing the order of various gates, both in terms of when they are implemented and where they are implemented (meaning qubit number). The other thing to test is whether the controlled unitaries use unitaries that are the complex conjugates of themselves or not. This was not true for the controlled y-rotation unitaries, but for the other controlled unitaries. For a small enough system, this should be a relatively quick process, but this will still take some time. This is not absolutely rigorous, but again, if you are not the most mathematically brilliant person, then this might just be the best way to do science. True respect for those who are mathematically rigorous though.

Thank you so much to those who appreciate this type of scientific thinking and I truly hope this helps!